# Find out what caused Windows screen on automatically

Tags: windows, display, event-log

I set the screen will be off after pressing the power button, but sometimes no matter how many times I try, the screen will turn on automatically seconds after it turning off, even if there's no mouse or keyboard input. How can I find what caused the screen turning on automatically?

Comment: Maybe. I'll test the next time I'm facing the issue. Thank you! @Martheen